# Can SetWindowHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC ) hang entire system?

Tags: c, winapi

I am stuck with this. I can't even see the debug output using OutputDebugString and debugview - the system just hangs.

One question is: if i call SendMessage() inside hook function, did this message comes to me back into my hook function or system just calls another handlers but not my?

Question two: I am using hook procedure to catch messages sent by the system when a user clicks the tray icons or moves the mouse over the icons.

Is this correct way using SetWindowHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, myfunc, hDll, 0) or should I use the thread parameter and set it to the thread which recieves msgs as configured by Shell_NotifyIcon()?

Comment: what handle do you send messages to ?

Comment: another thread's or process's window created by my dll

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the hook in a library!?

Regarding question 1: I would not call `SendMessage` inside the hook because this `SendMessage` again will let your hook being called. This might lead to a recursion.

Regarding question 2: You are using hooks to get notified when a tray icon was clicked? Do you want to now when ANY tray icon was clicked or when YOUR tray icon was clicked? For notifications about your tray icon you should use `Shell_NotifyIcon` and take a look at `NOTIFYICONDATA::uCallbackMessage`.